# Multiple controller for same view in AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

Is there any way that I can define two controller for the same templateUrl in angularjs using stateProvider like below?

```
//State Provider for dashBoard Screen
.state('dashBoard', {
    cache : false,
    url : "/dashBoard",
    templateUrl : dashBoardHtml,
    controller : ["FirstController","SecondController"]
})
```

The data binding logic is to heavy in my controller, the number of line is more than 1000, I have optimised, reduced cyclometic complexity everything. 
But now to make it more modularize I need to split the controller without change in the view like by not using any nested views.

Is there any way to define multiple contollers to same templateURL/html?

Comment: you want both controllers at once or seperate?

Comment: You could define one controller in the view and the other in the state

Comment: Try use multiple view in state

Comment: I think you need to use provider or service to modularize your app.

Answer (score 1):

This will work for you but if you want then you can use `ng-controller` directive as well

```
$stateProvider.state('view', {
    url: "/url",
    views: {
        'menuContent': {
            templateUrl: "template",
            controller: ['ctrl1', 'ctrl2']
        }
    }
});
```

example using diretive

```
    <div ng-controller="testController2">
            <!-- your view content -->
     </div>

    <div ng-controller="testController1">
            <!-- your view content -->
   </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you can put them into several services for business logic or directives for UI logic to make your code more clear and tidy.

Comment: This is probably the best solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can only assign one controller from the state and other one inside template like this

```
.state('dashBoard', {
    cache : false,
    url : "/dashBoard",
    templateUrl : dashBoardHtml,
    controller : FirstController
})
```

template

```
<div data-ng-controller="SecondController">
        <!-- your view content -->
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

your can assign controller on html

```
<div ng-controller="controller1"></div>
```

and on same HTML on other div

```
 <div ng-controller="controller2"></div>
```